# Compare a String using regex comparison

Tags: java, regex

I have to compare a String using regex comparison.

"***Shipped on Aug. 29, 2017***"

"**Shipped on**" will be the starting word in the sentence.I made it how ever its not working as expected.Can somebody help me

```
"(^Shipped on.* \\w.+\\s\\d{2},\\s\\d{4})"
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you have posted code on here without specifying what is wrong with it.  We expect to see what you expect the code to do, why you expect it to do this, what it is actually doing (with a full error message and stack trace where appropriate), and why it is wrong.  Please [edit] your question to include this information, and then I will consider retracting my downvote.

Comment: Your regex starts with matching (1) any characters between `Shipped on` and the date, (2) a space, (3) one character from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, (4) any characters multiple times (at least one). The rest looks fine. So in order to match, exchange `.` and `+` and then escape the dot (`\\.`).

Comment: Thanks steffen I will apply and let you know

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: [`Shipped on\s\w+\.\s\d{2},\s\d{4}`](https://regex101.com/r/3pikha/5)

**Java code**:

```
String string = "Shipped on Aug. 29, 2017";
Boolean isMatch = string.matches("Shipped on\\s\\w+\\.\\s\\d{2},\\s\\d{4}");
System.out.println(isMatch); // true
```